# How do I pipe the output of the journalctl to cURL?

Tags: linux, unix, curl, coreos

I am trying to send logs to a remote server using curl. I tried the following command and nothing happened

`journalctl -o json -f | curl -H "content-type:application/json" -d @- http://logs`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there something wrong with question why it was voted down?

Comment: Probably because people consider this method a bad idea, and aren't telling you what a good one is.

Comment: I really think these sites could be way more useful if downvoters indeed explained why they downvoted. It's especially rude to newcomers..

Comment: systemd already has several ways to send and receive journal entries to remote systems. Rolling your own doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @michael can you kindly suggest one?

Comment: Someone already did!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the correct way to retrieve JSON events over the internet is likely to be [`systemd-journal-gatewayd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-gatewayd.html)  You'll need to rewrite your other end to pull events from the server, but based on the documentation the server can stream JSON data if you add the `follow` parameter to the url:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:19531/entries?follow'
```

If your receiving application keeps track of the events it has received it can use the range header to avoid receiving duplicate events if it has to reconnect:

```
-H 'Range: cursorname:number_of_events_to_skip'
```

it's not clear from the documentation what `cursorname` is supposed to be, I suspect it is a unique name you make up so that gatewayd can keep track of events it has shown your application versus some other application that may also want log entries.

Alternatively you can use [`systemd-journal-remote`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.html) to receive journal entries in the native format on the remote computer, then use journalctl locally to receive the JSON data.

Comment: it seems that cursor is not just any unique name. There are cursors at points in the logs, which an also be shown using `journalctl --show-cursor`. However, it seems that cursorname is optional: `-H'Range: entries=:40:20'` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You may need `-X POST` in there to be sure how data is sent to the server, though it does seem to be implied in `-d`.

Your use of `-f` in journalctl makes it function like `tail -f` would, in that the stream stays open. This tells me your intent is to create a persistent HTTP tunnel that sends new log-lines to the log-server over http. Per the man-page:

> In normal work situations, curl will use a standard buffered output stream that will have the effect that it will output the data in chunks, not necessarily exactly when the data arrives.

That behavior doesn't match your intent. You probably want to also run with the `-N` or `--no-buffer` options so each line gets piped to curl as it comes in.

Comment: `-N` seems to be for curl's output, not for curl's input.  I'm about 90% certain that curl is going to sit there and wait for input to finish so that it can calculate the `Content-Length:` header.

Comment: That's my fear as well. CUrl may not start transmission until it has the whole datagram.